# Derived method in not called in base class

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I don't know how to put a right title. sorry by my problem is very hard with me.

I have a class myCal.h:

```
class myCal
{
public:
    myCal();
    int add(int a, int b);
    int sub(int a, int b);
    int expresstion(int a, int b, int c);
};
```

and myCal.cpp:

```
myCal::myCal()
{
}

int myCal::add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int myCal::sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a-b;
}

int myCal::expresstion(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return add(sub(a, b), c);
}
```

in main.cpp, i have class mockcal like this:

```
class mockcal : public myCal
{
public:
    int sub(int a, int b)
    {
        return 100;
    }
    int expresstion(int a, int b, int c)
    {
       return myCal::expresstion(a,b,c);
    }
};
```

if I run myCal.expresstion(3,2,1), the return value is 2, that's OK,
but when I run mockCal.expresstion(3,2,1), the return values still is 2, I want it return 101.

please help me to do this, but do not change anything in mockCal::expresstion.
Thanks so much.

Comment: If you write: int expresstion(int a, int b, int c)
    {
       return myCal::expresstion(a,b,c);
    } you'll have always 2

Comment: so what I need to do now, in myCal::expresstion call myCal::add and myCal::sub, I want myCal::sub always return 100, please help

Comment: write in expresstion of mockCal class an if about your instance object, so if instance is myCal (uppercasting) you'll cal myCal::expresstion otherwise you'll call mockCal override

Comment: @ĐứcNguyễnVăn `but do not change anything in mockCal::expresstion.`  So you want us to be up and down at the same time.  The `myCal` knows absolutely nothing about `mockKal`, so how is the `sub` of mockCal going to be called unless you change something?  The solution is to make `sub` virtual in myCal, plain and simple.  Anything else is either major hackery or impossible.

Comment: I know, seem that what I want to impossible..thanks everyone so much

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the method `int sub(int a, int b)` virtual in the base class ( `myCal` class in your code), if you want to override it in the `mockcal` class

```
class myCal
{
   public:
   //...
   virtual int sub(int a, int b);
   //..
};
```

Comment: I can't edit class myCal, only modify mockCal, can u give me suggest...:(

Comment: Do the calculations you require in _mokcal::expresstion_, don't return _myCal::expresstion(a,b,c)_.

Comment: I know, but I have to do that, I can't copy code from myCal::expresstion, but if you have any ideas, please post it, have any way to call expresstion method and this method cal mockcal::sub instead of myCal::sub...:(

Comment: Yes there is a method is in the answer ;)

Comment: Only virtual methods can be overridden in c++. Method `sub` is not virtual and cannot be overridden. In other words, you can't make method `sub` work another way it does.

Comment: @ĐứcNguyễnVăn - Also, in a real situation, if a programmer cannot edit the base class, then the base class is given back to the author of the base class to make the change.  There is no other way around it.